# some problems about modify IP address with System.Management(WMI)

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

1. I want to know the meaning of "ManagementObject" returnValue, such as '2147947410'.
2. Does C# have any other options to modify IP address, except through WMI?
3. How to prevent windows change IP address to 169.254.XXX, when it detect IP conflict?

---

1. Before run the code, I modify one network's IP address to 192.168.1.66(not my targe network).   [[Fig.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZINQ.png)]
2. Then run the code , it would not throw any exceptions, outPar["returnValue"] returns value 2147947410, but if I open target network's opions, the IP address is blank! [[Fig.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP79i.png)]
3. And, if type "ipconfig" in CMD, I will see the target network's IP is 169.254.XXX. I know that means "ip conflict". [[Fig.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP79i.png)]
4. Below is the code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Run Code in Admin mode.
            ManagementBaseObject inPar = null;
            ManagementBaseObject outPar = null;
            ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
            ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
            {
                if (!(bool)mo["IPEnabled"])
                    continue;
                string[] addresses = (string[])mo["IPAddress"];              
                Console.WriteLine("开始修改");
                try
                {
                    //设置ip地址和子网掩码 
                    inPar = mo.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");
                    inPar["IPAddress"] = new string[] { "192.168.1.66" };
                    inPar["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { "255.255.255.0" };
                    outPar = mo.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", inPar, null); 
                    Console.WriteLine(outPar["returnValue"]);
                    //设置网关地址 
                    inPar = mo.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways");
                    inPar["DefaultIPGateway"] = new string[] { "0.0.0.0" };
                    outPar = mo.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", inPar, null);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
                //设置DNS 
                inPar = mo.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");
                inPar["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = new string[] { "0.0.0.0" };
                outPar = mo.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", inPar, null);
                break;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://4sysops.com/archives/set-an-ip-address-and-configure-dhcp-with-powershell/, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-configure-static-ip-and-dns-settings/, https://www.pdq.com/blog/using-powershell-to-set-static-and-dhcp-ip-addresses-part-2/, and https://www.windowscentral.com/software-apps/windows-11/how-to-configure-a-static-ip-on-windows-10-or-11

Comment: [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapterconfiguration), [EnableStatic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/enablestatic-method-in-class-win32-networkadapterconfiguration#return-value), [SetGateways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/setgateways-method-in-class-win32-networkadapterconfiguration)